# How to find bitmap created from canvas is empty or not

Tags: android

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasLL.getawidth(), canvasLL.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_5);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap)
View.draw(canvas);
```

This how i had create a bitmap using the things draw on canvas. But i want to check that if something draw or not on the canvas. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap.getGenerationId()` can be used to check if a bitmap has been modified.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvasLL.getWidth(), canvasLL.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
final int oldBitmapId = bitmap.getGenerationId();

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
View.draw(canvas);

final int newBitmapId = bitmap.getGenerationId();
if (oldBitmapId != newBitmapId) {
    // a Bitmap has been changed
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping me Akaki, but it seems like not working. i had tried it is not working. i think the id is being changing every time it is writing. Actually i want to know that if that bitmap has something draw on it or not. is there anyway to find if bitmap is clear white image?